# Scala Dataframe NA values not being replaced

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to do a transformation on a dataframe using Scala in databricks.

In this I am trying to drop country_region where there is Null values and I am trying to fill up the remaining columns Active, Confirmed, Deaths and Recovered of NA with 0.

However, I notice that when I display the dataframe there are still null values in the Active, Confirmed, Deaths and Recovered columns.

```
val JHU_COVID_19: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("snowflake")
  .options(options)
  .option("dbtable", "JHU_COVID_19")
  .load()

val covid_19_grp = JHU_COVID_19.groupBy("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","CASE_TYPE","DATE")
                      .agg(count("CASE_TYPE").as("count"),sum("DIFFERENCE").as("sum"))
                      

//display(covid_19_dataset)

val covid_19_pivot = covid_19_grp.groupBy("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","DATE")
                .pivot("CASE_TYPE")
                .agg(min("sum"))

//cleaning the data
covid_19_pivot.na.drop(Seq("COUNTRY_REGION")).show(false)
covid_19_pivot.na.fill(0,Array("Active","Confirmed","Deaths","Recovered"))

//Inner join GOOG_GLOBAL_MOBILITY_REPORT with the covid_19_pivot
 val final_COVID_19_PREPARED = covid_19_pivot.join(mobility_dataset,Seq("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","DATE"))

display(final_COVID_19_PREPARED)
```

I then tried another way where I assigned variables to the intermediary transformations and this worked.

Does this mean I always need to assign variables? How can I do transformations like python on the dataframe without assigning an intermediary variable?

```
val JHU_COVID_19: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("snowflake")
  .options(options)
  .option("dbtable", "JHU_COVID_19")
  .load()

val covid_19_grp = JHU_COVID_19.groupBy("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","CASE_TYPE","DATE")
                      .agg(count("CASE_TYPE").as("count"),sum("DIFFERENCE").as("sum"))
                      

//display(covid_19_dataset)

val covid_19_pivot = covid_19_grp.groupBy("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","DATE")
                .pivot("CASE_TYPE")
                .agg(min("sum"))

//cleaning the data
val test = covid_19_pivot.na.drop(Seq("COUNTRY_REGION"))
val test2 = test.na.fill(0,Array("Active","Confirmed","Deaths","Recovered"))

//Inner join GOOG_GLOBAL_MOBILITY_REPORT with the covid_19_pivot
 val final_COVID_19_PREPARED = test2.join(mobility_dataset,Seq("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","DATE"))

display(final_COVID_19_PREPARED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe in spark is immutable in nature by design. Whenever you perform any transformation on a dataframe and you don't't assign it to a different dataframe variable then that transformation would happen but you won't be able to see that in the existing dataframe variable.

If you want instead of creating new dataframe variable for each of the transformations you could chain the transformation operations and once you are done with all the transformations assign that to a new dataframe variable and you would be able to incorporate all the changes.

Your Code as of now that works using separate variables.

```
val covid_19_pivot = covid_19_grp.groupBy("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","DATE")
                .pivot("CASE_TYPE")
                .agg(min("sum"))

//cleaning the data
val test = covid_19_pivot.na.drop(Seq("COUNTRY_REGION"))
val test2 = test.na.fill(0,Array("Active","Confirmed","Deaths","Recovered"))
```

Change that you need to make to chain the operation and not creating new variables.

```
val covid_19_pivot = covid_19_grp.groupBy("COUNTRY_REGION","PROVINCE_STATE","DATE")
                .pivot("CASE_TYPE")
                .agg(min("sum"))
                .na.drop(Seq("COUNTRY_REGION"))
         .na.fill(0,Array("Active","Confirmed","Deaths","Recovered"))
```

Comment: how do i change transformations? for example how do i do a na.dop and na.fill?